# Error in checking ArrayList elements (extracted from a csv file) in Java and parsing them using the required logic

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I read a CSV file,which looks as shown below.

```
,Tmt 1,Tmt 2,Tmt 3
delta 1,-104,-100,-103
delta 2,-125,-103,-103
delta 3,-104,-100,failed
```

Later, I parsed the csv file  and took in all of its elements to an ArrayList of Strings. 
Now the ArrayList looks like

```
[Tmt 1, Tmt 2, Tmt 3, delta 1, -104, -100, -103, delta 2, -125, -103, -103, delta 3, -104, -100, failed]
```

Now, I want to remove all the elements of the String ArrayList (shown above) which starts with an alphabet. I used the following code to do that.
(al1 is the ArrayList I mentioned above and temp is the String I'm using to check the elements of al1)

```
for(int i=0;i<al1.size();i++)
  {   
    temp = al1.get(i);  
    if (temp.charAt(0)=='-'|| (Character.isDigit(temp.charAt(0))==false))
           {
               al1.remove(i);    
           }    
  }
System.out.print(al1);
```

Now after the code runs and hoping to remove elements of al1 starting with an alphabet , I printed the ArrayList al1, and the result was as follows:

```
[Tmt 2, delts 1, -100, delta 2, -103, delta 3, -100]
```

(and this was not what I expected)

Please Help.. thanks in advance

Comment: Well what *did* you expect, and why? Have you stepped through this with a debugger, and worked out where things are going wrong? Have you determined whether the problem is with using the list, or with your string handling? One thing to bear in mind: if you remove an item from your list, everything else shuffles up... so the next item you want to check will have the *same* index as the one you just removed. You can fix that by adding `i--` after the `remove` call. Or you could work your way from the *end* of the list towards the start.

Comment: Or you could just create another list containing only the elements you want to keep.

Comment: Jon Skeet, I was expecting that the resulting arraylist was devoid of elements starting with an alphabet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using index to remove the element.

When you remove one element, your `i` will be off, after first removal you will not be removing the correct element.

Say your `i` is `5` and you have removed that element, in the next iteration when `i` is `6`, when you do `al1.get(i)` you will actually get `7th` element in the original list, not 6th because your 6th element index now is `5` but not `6`. So you will not be able to access that element at all.

your `for(int i=0;i<al1.size();i++)` is also incorrect, because you are incrementing `i` and reducing the size of `al1`.

In worst case(`when all the elements in the list starts with '-'`), you will be able to traverse only half of the elements.

Safer way to do is using an Iterator.

```
Iterator<> it = al1.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
     temp = it.next();  
     if (temp.charAt(0)=='-'|| (Character.isDigit(temp.charAt(0))==false))
       {
           it.remove();    
       }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's happening.

The list is `Tmt1, Tmt2, Tmt3, ...`. At the beginning, element 0 is `Tmt1`.

We consider this one for removal; it starts with a letter; so we remove it, and then move onto element 1 (the second one). *But* by that point we've removed one, so the list OS now `Tmt2, Tmt3, ...`, and we're considering the second one in the list, which is `Tmt3`! `Tmt2` never gets looked at because it shifts backwards at the same time that your list shuffles forwards.

The nicest way to deal with this is the Java 8 streams API, which allows you to specify a filter over your list, and have it automatically remove all elements that don't meet the filter's requirements. It's concise and readable and much easier than a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

you can use built-in `removeif` method as:

```
al1.removeIf(new Predicate<String>() {

            @Override
            public boolean test(String t) {
                 if (t.charAt(0)=='-'|| (Character.isDigit(t.charAt(0))==false)){
                       return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: removeIf() only exists since Java 8. So why not use a lambda instead of an anonymous class? `al1.removeIf(t -> t.charAt(0)=='-'|| !Character.isDigit(t.charAt(0)));`. Every time you have `if (condition) return true; else return false;`, you can write it `return condition;`